# C# running a scheduled program a specific amount of time depending on user input

Tags: c#, logging, cmd, scheduled-tasks

I have a web form that calls a .exe c# program daily. The .exe program is a database restore and it needs to be ran a specific amount of times.(depending on how many databases need to be restored that day) Right now I'm using task scheduler and calling the .exe at a certain time(5 pm daily). The web form writes to a log file like:

dbName: 'test' 
ServerToRestoreTo:'ServerName'

So sometimes there are more than 1 dbName and more than 1 ServerToRestoreTo. And I need that task scheduler synced accordingly.

Comment: Please provide examples of what you have tried/hasn't worked, so we may assist you in *fixing* your issue.

Comment: Hi, right now I am using task scheduler to call the program. I don't have actual code for the task scheduler part. I was wondering if there was a way to set the amount of times the program runs through task scheduler on windows.Thanks!